# Processing Instruction in XML File

Tags: xml

**Processing Instruction:** Used to pass an instruction to applications that processing this file. Processing instructions are written in the following syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Why is this necessary? Can't an application or machine understand tags without processing instruction line? Is this a standart or recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a processing instruction. It's the XML declaration.

And yes, it's completely optional. It's only necessary if your XML file does not match the defaults, which are `version="1.0"`, `encoding="UTF-8"` and `standalone="yes"` (and these are not actual attributes, but pseudo-attributes).

The XML declaration configures the parser, it is not part of the resulting document.

In contrast, actual processing instructions that may follow later *are* part of the document.

And yes, of course. [It's a standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl).

Comment: Whare are the advantages and disadvantages of it?

Comment: The advantages are that you can tell the parser that your XML file does not match the defaults. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: For example if I use SAXParser in Java, Can I get values without `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Comment: Quote *"it's completely optional. It's only necessary if your XML file does not match the defaults"*.

Comment: But here says opposite to you: http://www.herongyang.com/XML/Syntax-the-xml-Processing-Instruction.html

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. It is not required, just try it. -- It's required to include the `version` pesudo-attribute **if, and only if** you decide to use an XML declaration.

Comment: @hakiko - The XML declaration is only required if the XML version is 1.1. If the declaration is omitted, it's a 1.0 XML document. http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: @Daniel ...or if the file `encoding` is not UTF-8, or if `standalone` is "no". As I keep saying. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak - Of course. I meant other than for those reasons. :-)