# Modifying xml file without changing special chars

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file with structure:

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
 <a>
   <b>
      <d>
         <LineCode>0</LineCode>
         <LineName>Metro</LineName>
         <LineDescription>Test C&#38;C all countries with MCFM</LineDescription>
      </d>
      .......
      <e>.....</e>
      <f>....</f>
  </b>
 </a>
```

In this file I have added section  with following code:

```
                XElement newElement = new XElement("e",
                    new XElement("e1", "test1"),
                    new XElement("e2", "test2"),
                    new XElement("e3", "test3 ));

                doc.Root.Element("a").Element("d").AddAfterSelf(newElement);
                doc.Save(file.Directory + "//" + file.Name);
```

After i run this code all my special chars used in the initial XML file are modified .
For exemple first row became:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

line became:

```
 <LineDescription>Test C&amp;C all countries with MCFM</LineDescription>
```

How to add the new section in my XML file without modifying the existing chars?Or how to save without modifying existing special chars?

Comment: Why does it matter that you change that part?

Comment: I only want to keep initial chars .This files are used by other applications and is possible to be problems at reading or processing this new files .

Comment: I would test to see if this was a problem before trying to "fix" this. The XML standard allows for these things so the programs that read the files should cope with it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**== Observation #1 ==**

```xml
<!-- Before: -->
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<!-- After: -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Explanation: If the `encoding` attribute is omitted, [`utf-8` is the default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15441117/1497596).

**== Observation #2 ==**

```xml
<!-- Before: -->
&#38;

<!-- After: -->
&amp;
```

Explanation: These **XML entities** for representing the [ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) **are equivalent**.

**== Summary ==**

> The new files are to be used by other applications and it is possible that there
>   might be problems reading or processing the new files.

***Well-behaved*** XML processing software should treat your before- and after- documents in an equivalent fashion. So, if you encounter problems reading or processing the newly edited XML files, those problems really should be addressed. But it is possible that you may not have the kinds of problems that you anticipate.

Answer (score 1):

If the code processing your file is supposed to handle standard XML, it should not matter which form the characters are stored in. Your original file is using the numeric code for the character, while the newly saved file is using the standard entity name. The same applies for the XML header line - version='1.0' and version="1.0" - should be treated exactly the same, and the additional element just identifies which character set was used in writing the file.

Provided your other applications are using standard XML parsers, or custom parsers which are capable of reading standard XML there should be no problem with the modified XML. The only issue you might have is if these other applications cannot read standard XML (ie they assume that all values use single quotes, or they don't correctly process the XML standard entities, etc) - in this case you may need to use a filtering parser on any file sent to those applications to ensure that these requirements are met. (ie a simple SAX parser which writes out the file as the events are triggered using the additional limitations)